# Create an external load balancer to Cloud CDN with Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, load-balancing, google-cloud-cdn, url-masking

I try configure my Google Cloud Functions by using CDN.
I try use this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-cdn-with-serverless

With one function as Backend Endpoint looks all good, and if I open Load Balancing Frontend IP I see same result as I open direct function URL. And seems that this means this function now work over CDN if I use this IP.

But I have too many functions, because of this I try use URL mask for all functions in my Endpoint.
URL mask looks like this:

```
https://us-central1-my-real-project.cloudfunctions.net/<function>
```

Problem that I cant understand how I can use Load Balancing Frontend IP for my Endpoint with Cloud Functions created with URL mask.
When I open Load Balancing IP I get:

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

PS. Same if I try open `http://<load-balancing-frontend-ip>/my-function-name`

**UPD:**

Configurations in screenshots placed in google drive:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eI9tx_SQcJ_uJrlt-xzeZua9bwklszik?usp=sharing

(*sorry, not know how share other way configuration, and cant attach images direct in question because of low reputation*)

Comment: Can you share your configuration?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere was edit question, and add configuration, thank you for your attention

Comment: use that url mask `/<function>`. I think that's your issue. If so, I will answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#constructing-url-mask), the URL mask must be only `/<function>`. No URL before.